# Bash script runs through files in a directory but in the wrong order

Tags: shell, sorting, sh, batch-rename

I'm creating a dataset with multiple JPEG files from multiple directories and the files in each directory are named "1.jpg", "2.jpg" ... "100.jpg". This means that the files in each directory all start with "1.jpg".

My goal is to merge all images in one folder and for that I've tried to rename the files of the second directory to continue at the number of the last file from the first directory i.e. if the last file of the first directory is "668.jpg" I'd like to rename all files from the second directory starting with "669.jpg".

I've used [this script](https://askubuntu.com/a/809017/1154422) to rename the files and almost does the job:

```
counter=668
for file in *; do 
    [[ -f $file ]] && echo mv -i "$file" $((counter+1)).png && ((counter++))
done
```

The problem is that the script seems to be picking the wrong order and instead of reading the files in numeric ascending order (1,2,3..., 100) it reads and renames them in this order: 100,101, 102, 103, 104,105,106,107,108, 109, 10, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117,118,119, 11 ...

By reading the files in this order it is screwing up the order since the first file to be renamed into 669.jpg should be 1.jpg and not 100.jpg.

Why is it reading the files in this order and how do I fix this?

My guess was to use a while do instead of a for loop or perhaps I should include a numerical sort but I can't figure out the syntax.

Comment: if all your .jpg file start with digits, check the ordering from this: `ls *.jpg | sort -n`

Comment: How about `for i in {1..100} ; do mv $i.jpg ...`